Mule Getting timestamp format issue
My date input is createdate=20230425(yyyyMMdd) and I am trying to delete records from oracle database
Query: Delete from employee where create_date = :createDate
In oracle,field DataType is DATE (25-APR-23) format
In Mule I am getting below timestamp format Error.
Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.ffffffff]
Please help above error to resolve and your solution much appreciated

[edit] the question to add a [mre]. Is the input a string or a date type? Which type? Add the flow componenrts and the complete error messages.

It is a bit hard to tell because there is missing information in the question but the error indicates that the data is missing time information (Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.ffffffff]).
Assuming the input is a String you could convert to date, add the time as the zero hour of the day and convert back to String with the desired format using builtin date-time functions and conversions:
%dw 2.0
output application/java
import * from dw::core::Dates
var createdate="20230425"
---
(createdate as Date {format: "yyyyMMdd"} ++ localTime({ hour: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0})) as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}

Output (String):
2023-04-25 00:00:00

